# Approximation in $V^{**}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

We know that for a vector space $V$ there is a natural map $\iota\colon V\to V^{**}$ sending $v$ to $v^{**}$.

When $V$ is a normed space, $\iota$ is an isometry, however it may not be surjective. My question is whether arbitrary vectors of $V^{**}$ can be approximated (in any sense) by the vectors in the image of $\iota$ for an arbitrary Banach space $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is [Goldstine's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstine_theorem) which asserts that $\iota(V)$ is weakly* dense in $V^{**}$. Of course, $\iota(V)$ is norm-closed in $V^{**}$ as $\iota$ is an isometry.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#The_weak-.2A_topology for the definition of the weak*-topology.